# How do I distinguish Code Review from Stack Overflow in cases like this?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-review-se

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039336/how-to-use-whenever-gem-to-run-a-task-at-2-am-and-2-pm) which was migrated from Code Review to Stack Overflow.

My first intention was to put it in CR because:

- I had no technical problem; the code worked.
- I did not intend to change the execution result. In other words, my goal was not "I could do X but I still need to do Y". The executed result would be the same in requirement.
- My intention, although related to a library, was to make my code cleaner.

This one did not bring my any trouble or rep or closure. Just a migration. But I want to distinguish the proper usage of those sites in these cases to avoid annoying people with subsequent migrations.

How can I distinguish these use cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally voted to migrate your question because you weren't looking for a review; you were looking for one solution and that solution was not likely to be a language construct. If we had left your question on Code Review, it's likely it wouldn't have been answered. On Stack Overflow, such as question would likely to be answered quickly.

That said, questions like yours are perfectly valid for Code Review! They're also perfectly valid for Stack Overflow. It all depends on what you want to get out of answers; Code Review answers will target any aspect of your code, which is great if you're looking for improvement of specific code, whilst Stack Overflow is better at solving a specific problem.

And in your case, what you really seemed to have is a specific problem (how do I target multiple times with 1 cron task). You didn't do anything wrong in posting on Code Review, but Stack Overflow was a better fit.

---

For context, take a look at our chat transcript:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28289861#28289861

The bot posts the question in chat from there and we discuss it, eventually deciding to move it based on the fact that it is a 'specific programming question'.

Comment: Isn't one of the first questions of migration: Is it off-topic at the current site?

Comment: @SimonForsberg but it's on-topic for Code Review... it's not likely to get answered, however. Could take weeks before there's an answer. On Stack Overflow, it got answered within an hour. For questions like this, Stack Overflow is just better

Comment: @SimonForsberg But was it actually on-topic for Code Review? [On-topic help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says: "Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?". OP was requesting a very specific re-write, not a general review. This question was rightfully migrated IMO (I ones one of the voters).

Comment: @Mast from what I'm reading, OP was like "Here's my problem, I'd like a solution, but if you find anything else, let me know". So yes, they'd want feedback on all facets.

Comment: @Mast From experience about how we handle questions that answer No to that question on CR, I'd say that saying no to that question is usually not a good reason on its own for migrating the question.